# How to get the parent of the parent of a component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got following hierarchy:

[image]

The marked item has a Collider, which gets hit by a raycast. How can I access from the ColliderComponent of the Cylinder upwards to "fass1"?

```
   RaycastHit e;
   [...]
   e.collider.???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the **Cylinder89** object is your `e.collider`, accessing **fass1**'s Collider can be done with:

```
e.collider.transform.parent.parent.GetComponent<Collider>();
```